# Android calendar project, compile errors

Tags: android, compiler-errors, calendar

I'm trying to compile the Android calendar project.  But I have a few resource file errors, such as these attributes, saying that no resource match is found:

```
android:color="@color/done_text_color_disabled"
android:textColor="@drawable/list_item_font_primary"
android:textColor="@drawable/list_item_font_secondary"
android:background="@color/white"
android:textColor="@color/done_text_color"
```

I'm assuming I need some common Android resource library?  Can I fix this without downloading a massive library?  I checked and the docs seemed to be oriented towards Linux.  I'm using WinXP (no haters).

-Mike

Comment: @android:color/_ for built in android colors

Comment: here you will find your missing drawable and colors 
https://github.com/Timmmm/MMS/tree/master/res/drawable

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google's Android repository code cannot be compiled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856776/googles-android-repository-code-cannot-be-compiled)